# Graphql: Unable to query (where:{author}) for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, query

I have created a custom post type (jobPosts).

I'm using Gatsby/Graphql/Apollo to query and mutate data.

**Problem:** I need to grab job posts from Wordpress to for a specific user.

I would like to query the jobPosts by 'author', but the Graphiql interface does not give me the option to use 'where' with 'author' (it doesn't exist in the scheme?):

[image]

Desired query:

```
`{
    query getJobs($userId: Int!) {
        jobPosts (where: {author: $userId}) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    databaseId
                    jobPostFields {
                        title
                        sector
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

Does anyone know how to add this functality to the schema / add 'author' to the '(where:{})' filter? Or another way to get this filtered data, without having to pull all the job posts and using something expensive like data.filter()?

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: did you add support for author when you created the cpt?  `"supports" => array( "title", "editor", "author" )`

Comment: This solved it thanks!

Comment: awesome.  I posted as an answer below.  Could you check it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add support for the author when you create your custom post type.

Make sure that you add to your supports array so it's similar to this:

```
"supports" => array( "title", "editor", "author" ),
```

This will allow your GraphiQL to have that data!

You MAY need to go back to each post and re-save them though as they don't have any author data until you do!